# Где хранить конфиг для подключения?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, laravel

Разрабатываю приложение на laravel 5 целью которого является публикация постов в различных социальных сетях.
Предполагается что социальных сетей будет много и для каждой из них используется свой конфиг для подключения, типа "access_token", "user_id" и т.д.
Дело в том что поля будут абсолютно разные исходя из типа социальной сети.

**Вопрос:** Где и как лучше хранить такой конфиг для подключения?

Если в голове 3 варианта решения.

1. Хранить данные о подключении в .env файле (это не самый лучший вариант, потому что заносить данные придется вручную)
2. Хранить данные в бд, в таблице текущей социальной сети (не лучший вариант, потому что поля в таблице будут существенно разные и плодить пустые колонки не охото.)
3. При создании ресурса социальной сети создавать отдельную папку в файловой системе и в ней хранить config для подключения.

Comment: Как вариант сделай таблицу `options` с полями `id`, `key(string)`, `value(json)`. И нужные параметры сохраняй в json

Answer (score 1):

Выбор того или иного способа для хранения настроек зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения и логики его работы:

- Если архитектура построена так, что при добавлении новой соцсети вам нет необходимости писать новый код, а настройки доступа унифицированы (например, поле access_token), то тогда есть смысл хранить такие сущности в бд и управлять ими через админку. (Создание/чтение/изменение/удаление). Учитывая, что соцсети достаточно сильно различаются между собой в механизме доступа к ним и обмене данными, мала вероятность что вам не потребуется писать код при подключении новой соцсети.
- Если при добавлении новой соцсети потребуется реализовать некий код (что наиболее вероятно), то имеет смысл выносить настройки в конфигурационные файлы Laravel. Если конфигурация отличается в разных средах (dev или production), имеет смысл использовать .env файл и соответствующую функцию env() внутри конфигурационных файлов. Также имеет место реализация каждой отдельной соцсети в виде отдельного модуля Laravel, имеющего свой собственный конфигурационный файл в рамках модуля.